# Wait for either of two "user input" tasks to finish, abort the other

Tags: c#, task, user-input, fingerprint

Basically I have two inputs i need to wait for.

1. Receives a fingerprint from the fingerprint sensor for authentication
2. Receives a user key input for cancellation of the fingerprint authentication

This is my function using only input No.1 that **should** contain both:

```
public static bool Identify(out FingerId identity)
{
    bool interrupted = false; // should be changed if user entered key and not finger

    Console.Write("Enter any key to cancel. ");
    // Should run along with "Console.ReadKey()"
    FingerBio.Identify(_session, out Finger._identity);

    identity = Finger._identity;
    return interrupted;
}
```

Comment: Put each type of authentication onto an async method, then use Task.WaitAny().

Comment: @Joe Even better await Task.WhenAny(...)

Comment: I would set up a continuation that cancels both tasks and then does the work on complete login. Of course there are some questions about UI design (like how should the UI respond to a login try/notify of failed Fingerprint attempt)

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) along with [`Task.WhenAny`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany(v=vs.110).aspx).

Since your question does not have a lot of details about your user interfaces tasks, here is a demo with the general sense of the pattern.

The demo emulates your user interface tasks with `Task.Run(...)`. The second task emulates a long running task by using an infinite loop. When the first task finishes, then we cancel the second one.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8usHLX

```
public class Program
{
    public async Task Identify() 
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cts.Token;

        var task1 = Task.Run(async () => {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Task1");
        }, token);

        var task2 = Task.Run(async () => {
            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine("Task2");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }, token);

        // When one of them completes, cancel the other.        
        // Try commenting out the cts.Cancel() to see what happens.
        await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2);
        cts.Cancel();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Identify().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

The `Main()` method has a `Task.Delay()` at the end to keep the program running long enough for the demo to make sense.

Comment: I tried it, but the Console.ReadKey() doesn't actually cancel at all, the next character i enter is considered for the readkey function

Comment: I'm need more details. Could you please post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of what you're trying to do. That would help me to better understand your constraints. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I will do so tomorrow, appreciate the help!